# How to center an element?

Tags: css, html

I want to center an element for uploading files. Now it is left-aligned.

```
<p class="text-muted">Bla-bla-bla
<input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" onchange="document.getElementById('moreUploadsLink').style.display = 'block';" />
</p>
```

I tested `).text-align = 'center';"`, but it does not work.

UPDATE:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                    <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                    </span>
                    <h4 class="service-heading">Practical Session #1</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted" style="text-align:center;">Bla-bla-bla
                    <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" onchange="document.getElementById('moreUploadsLink').style.display = 'block';" /></p>              
                </div>
```

[image]

Comment: With `text-align:center;` https://jsfiddle.net/33191hsp/ as described in the duplicate question.

Comment: @web-tiki: Thank you. However I don't want to touch my CSS style sheet, because <p> has different settings in other parts of the code. I want to apply centering to my particular element.

Comment: use inline style: https://jsfiddle.net/33191hsp/1/

Comment: @web-tiki: Still doesn't work in my code. ok, thanks. I'll check other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the inline style :
style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;
this should fix it

```
<div class="buttonHolder">
<p class="text-muted" style="text-align:center;">Bla-bla-bla</p>
<input type="file" name="attachment" class="attachment" onchange="document.getElementById('moreUploadsLink');" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;"/></p>              

</div>
```

Comment: The `<center>` element [is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)

Comment: @web-tiki: You've marked it as a duplicate question. I tried solutions proposed in the duplicate thread. Still nothing works.

Comment: try changing 
<p class="text-muted">
for 
<p class="text-align">

Comment: No, it doesn't help. Just the color style of a text is changed.

Comment: @TheoLeinad can you please explain how only changing the class of the element can affect it's styling?

Comment: The style should be already stated in the CSS, I thought he was using a proper CSS, I just edited the answer (from the duplicate quesiton/answer)
It should work (for the text). 
To center the button margin-left and right need to be setted as auto, as far as I remember.

Comment: Adding .buttonHolder{ text-align: center; } to the main style sheet neither solved this particular issue. I still have the text Bla-bla-bla centered, while the Button is left-aligned.

Comment: can you explain with code and images, seems your issue is so simple, but hard to understand...

Comment: Please see my update. I tried to add <div class="buttonHolder">, but it didn't help. That's why in the Update I put my original code.

Comment: I am using this template: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/agency/
This is the GitHub link: https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-agency/tree/gh-pages/css
The CSS file is called agency.css. I cannot post it here because it's quite long.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos well the <center> </center> tag worked for me, place the input button in the middle of this tags...

Comment: Thanks. This tag will be removed, however I will use it for a temporal problem solving.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos Just fixed it, please try the CSS solution, if not, I'm out of ideas, thanks :)